# Discord commands error: Command cannot be found

Tags: discord, pycharm, discord.py

I'm trying to make a leveling feature to my discord bot but I'm facing some issues. Here's the code. Comes with an error when I type `!xp` it comes with this, not sure how to fix.

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "xp" is not found.
```

I also have a separate file named 'lvldb.json'.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio
import json

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

client = discord.Client()

m = {}

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global m
    with open("lvldb.json", "r") as j:
        m = json.load(j)
        j.close()
    if len(m) == 0:
        m = {}
        for member in client.get_guild(GUILDTOKEN).members:
            m[str(member.id)] = {"xp": 0, "messageCountdown": 0}
    print("ready")
    while True:
        try:
            for member in client.get_guild(GUILDOTOKEN).members:
                m[str(member.id)]["messageCountdown"] -= 1
        except:
            pass
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global m
    if message.content == "!stop" and message.author.id == ID:
        with open("lvldb.json", "w") as j:
            j.write(json.dumps(m))
            j.close()
        await client.close()
    elif message.content == "!xp":
        await message.channel.send(str( m[str(message.author.id)]["xp"]))
    elif message.author != client.user:
        if m[str(message.author.id)]["messageCountdown"] <= 0:
            m[str(message.author.id)]["xp"] += 10
            m[str(message.author.id)]["messageCountdown"] = 10


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    m[str(member.id)] = {"xp": 0, "messageCountdown": 0}
```

Comment: That only happens if you make a `commands.Bot` and then you have a prefix but it doesn't match anything. Are you sure that you aren't using `Bot` somewhere? Can you add the full traceback to the question?

Comment: @EricJin Thats the full Traceback, it only says that command isnt found. I'll edit the message to show my full code.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Where is the bot or client run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating both a `commands.Bot` and `discord.Client`. You don't want to do this; `Bot` is already a subclass of the generic client and can do everything it needs to do. Only make one, such as

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
```

---

You're also getting the error because discord.py thinks the user is trying to invoke a command when it starts with the prefix. It tries to get the command but then raises exception when it can't. You can silently ignore it (see [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L302)):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, err):
    if err.__class__ is commands.errors.CommandNotFound:
        # who cares?
        return
    print('oh no, an error occured, printing it:', file=sys.stderr)
    traceback.print_exception(type(err), err, err.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)
```